# Can't run Hello World java program on Windows

Tags: java, windows

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Set your print into the console
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I have tried executing the program through command prompt(cmd.exe), yet it keeps on bringing errors as its output.

I expected to get hello World, but I get:

```
Error: could not find or load main class MyClass.java
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: What command you use in `cmd` to compile and run program?

Comment: `Error: could not find or load main class MyClass.java` The name is wrong in two respects. 1) Your class is called `Main`, not `MyClass`. 2) The JVM launches a `.class` file, not the `.java` source code file.

Comment: *"You can only post once in 90mins"* No, don't post a new question, [edit] the current question! An existing question can be edited at *any* time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave little to no information it's hard to tell where the error is.

Here's the code which would print 'Hello World'

```
public class Main {
    //Class name is irrelevent, but it must be the same as the filename

    //Define a main method, it HAS to be public, static and called 'main' and should     
    //receive a String array and return void (just copy the next row)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Set your print into the console
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

Now compile your file by typing in the terminal:

`javac <the path to your .java file>`

And then:

`java <classname (here Main)>`

Comment: thanks alot, but that is the same code i am having here. Have been trying to post it but has not gone through.

Comment: Could you try posting it again? Also do you use a package?

Comment: Please how can post my code for it has detected as not code format.

Comment: Place four spaces before each line - there's an instruction at the top of the text area where you write your post.

Comment: It writes" You can only post once in 90mins"